# String array to a hashtable

Tags: c#, arraylist, hashtable

I'm trying to fill a `HashTable` with a string array from a `.txt` file.

Currently, I am reading the `.txt` file from a directory, but can´t fill the hashtable with a `foreach` loop.

I am getting the below:

> Syntax error; value expected

Any help is much appreciated!

```
  static Hashtable GetHashtable()
  {
   // Create and return new Hashtable.
      Hashtable ht_rut = new Hashtable();
   //Create a string from all the text
      string rutcompleto = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\datos rut.txt");
   //create an array from the string split by ,
      String[] rutArr = rutcompleto.Split(',');
   //create a int key for the hashtable
      int key = 1;
        
        foreach (var item in rutArr)
        {
            ht_rut.Add(key,rutArr[]);
            key = key + 1;
        }

        return ht_rut;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
ht_rut.Add(key,rutArr[]);
```

with

```
ht_rut.Add(key,item);
```

since you want to add the item instead of the whole array

---

you could also solve this with linq:

```
static Hashtable GetHashtable()
{
    string[] rutcompleto = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\datos rut.txt").Split(',');
    return new Hashtable(Enumerable.Range(1, rutcompleto.Count()).ToDictionary(x => x, x => rutcompleto[x-1]));
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, my query was wrong soo Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`rutArr[]` is not a valid C# syntax, you need to use `rutArr[index]` or the iteration variable inside foreach `item`:

```
foreach (var item in rutArr)
{
    ht_rut.Add(key, item);
    key = key + 1;
}
```